# Viewpager Adapter getItem always called for index 0 and 1

Tags: android, android-viewpager, position, adapter

I was just wondering if it is the normal behaviour of `viewpager` and its adapter to always call the `getItem()` method for index 0 and 1, even if I immediately set a current position.

Here is my code:

```
mNewsPagerAdapter = new NewsDetailPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
mNewsPagerAdapter.updateNewsList(news);

mViewPager = (ViewPager) mView.findViewById(R.id.horizontal_view_pager);
mViewPager.setPageMargin(2);
mViewPager.setPageMarginDrawable(R.color.black);

mViewPager.setAdapter(mNewsPagerAdapter);
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mCurrentPositionPager, false);
```

If I switch from my overview activity to my detail activity with this `viewpager`, the adapter always calls the `getItem()` method for position 0 and 1 and after that the `getItem()` method for the position of `mOriginalPosition` and its neighbors. I was wondering if this is the correct behaviour or if I missed something to implement it in a right way. Thanks for your help :)

Edit: Added my adapter code

```
public class NewsDetailPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private SparseArray<Fragment> mPageReferenceMap = new SparseArray<Fragment>();

private ArrayList<News> mNewsList;

public NewsDetailPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

/**
 * Setzt die neuen News.
 **/
public void updateNewsList(ArrayList<News> list) {
    mNewsList = list;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Log.d("debug", "getItem position:" + position);
    News newsItem = mNewsList.get(position);


    NavigationFragment fragment = new NavigationFragment();

    mPageReferenceMap.put(position, fragment);

    return fragment;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNewsList.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}

public Fragment getFragment(int position) {
    return mPageReferenceMap.get(position);
}
```

}

Comment: what value you are returing from Newspageradapert's getcount method

Comment: @jennymo What position you're setting ?

Comment: post your adapter code

Comment: Hello, my getCount-Method returns usually a value between 10 and 12 depending on the amount of data I got from our api :) The position is set according to the users click, for example 8. And also then he calls getItem for index 0 and 1

Comment: Added my adapter code  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is the normale behavior. In fact, as soos as you associate the  ViewPager with the adapter, the adapter creates the first visibile layout (index 0) end the next one (index 1). This is done by default in the "setAdapter". Then, when you set a different position, the adapter will instantiate the fragment at the selected index, the previous one and the next one.

This is the usual ViewPager setAdapter code:

```
public void setAdapter(PagerAdapter adapter) {
    if (mAdapter != null) {
        mAdapter.setViewPagerObserver(null);
        mAdapter.startUpdate(this);
        for (int i = 0; i < mItems.size(); i++) {
            final ItemInfo ii = mItems.get(i);
            mAdapter.destroyItem(this, ii.position, ii.object);
        }
        mAdapter.finishUpdate(this);
        mItems.clear();
        removeNonDecorViews();
        mCurItem = 0;
        scrollTo(0, 0);
    }

    final PagerAdapter oldAdapter = mAdapter;
    mAdapter = adapter;
    mExpectedAdapterCount = 0;

    if (mAdapter != null) {
        if (mObserver == null) {
            mObserver = new PagerObserver();
        }
        mAdapter.setViewPagerObserver(mObserver);
        mPopulatePending = false;
        final boolean wasFirstLayout = mFirstLayout;
        mFirstLayout = true;
        mExpectedAdapterCount = mAdapter.getCount();
        if (mRestoredCurItem >= 0) {
            mAdapter.restoreState(mRestoredAdapterState, mRestoredClassLoader);
            setCurrentItemInternal(mRestoredCurItem, false, true);
            mRestoredCurItem = -1;
            mRestoredAdapterState = null;
            mRestoredClassLoader = null;
        } else if (!wasFirstLayout) {
            populate();
        } else {
            requestLayout();
        }
    }

    if (mAdapterChangeListener != null && oldAdapter != adapter) {
        mAdapterChangeListener.onAdapterChanged(oldAdapter, adapter);
    }
}
```

In order to change the ViewPager behavior, you could extend the classic ViewPager overriding the setAdapter method and set the mCurrItem to the desired position.

I hope it helped

## Edit:

After different tests, we found a solution.

If the ViewPager adapter is set after ViewPager layout become visible, items 0 and 1 are load.
If you want to avoid this behavior but you can't set the adapter before the layout become visible (because you are waiting for data), than you can use this workaround:

1) Set the ViewPager visibility initially to GONE

2) After you receive all the data, you update the adapter and you set the current item value

3) Finally you set the ViewPager visibility to VISIBLE

Here you can find an example:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail_overview_fragment, container, false);

    final int position = getArguments().getInt("position");
    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            viewPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
            viewPager.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    },5000);

    return v;
}
```

Comment: But I got another project with a default android viewpager and it doesn't show the described behaviour...so I think there has to be a mistake in my code. Unfortunately I'm not able to spot the difference in the two implementations as they almost look the same -.-

Comment: Can you share somehow the project where the viewPager doesn't load the fragments at index 0 and 1 as the setAdapter occurs? That's the "strange" behavior and I'm quite sure that there's something strange in the setup..

Comment: This is the link to the project: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1aHkcAaWIA-NGhVYUtzcnVKU1k. As you can see it's really a simple implementation and the adapter doesn't create the fragments at index 0 and 1 if I choose element 15 for example. I want this behaviour in my app project above because of permance issues :D So I'm really sceptical if the creation of the two previous fragments 0 and 1 is the really the desired behaviour of google... :)

Comment: You are right! I was able to replicate the correct behavior you described. In order to be more specific in describing the differences between the correct and the wrong ViewPager setup, can you link me also the "wrong" project? In this way I can revise my previous statement more in depth. Thank you!

Comment: Sure. It is a very complex project, I will try to simplify it. Just give me 1 or 2 days and hopefully I can simplify the project without getting rid of the special behaviour ;-)

Comment: Great! Thanks. Can you show me the .gradle file and the import of the ViewPager? So I Can check the project target, the dependencies list and the ViewPager import.

Comment: In the process of simplifying my project I was able to reproduce the desired behaviour (without viewpager calling getItem for Index 0 and 1). I will try to explain:

Comment: Current state: The fragment which contains the viewpager starts loading data from the database in its onCreateView method. As soon as the data has finished loading, the fragment initializes the viewpager and its adapter (as shown in my first code snippet in my question). The viewpager calls getItem additionally for index 0 and 1. If I change the location of the viewpager initialization to be executed already in onCreateView getItem isn't called for index 0 and 1 (if I set the current item of viewpager to 8 for example). But I still didn't understand this behaviour.... :D

Comment: In the end, the ViewPager behavior just depends on the layout visibility. In fact the behavior remains "normal" also for asynchronous loading if you set the ViewPager visibility initially to GONE and than you change  ViewPager visibility to VISIBLE just after the adapter is updated with new data  and the current item is set.

Comment: Yes you are right. I set the ViewPager visibility to GONE and change its visibility to VISIBLE right after I called setCurrentItem of the viewpager. Now  the pager no longer call getItem for fragment 0 and 1, if I click fragment 8 for example. So much thanks for your help! In most cases the mistake is much more easier than expected :D I'll mark your answer as the right one :)

Answer (score 3):

It is normal (and intelligent in my opinion). 
ViewPager class has one property named mOffscreenPageLimit with default value of 1. This number determines how many pages on the left and on the right of the current page that the Viewpager will preload. For instance, you have 10 pages, current position is 5 and mOffcreenPageLimit is 1, the page at position 4 and 6 will be loaded.

You could change this property by calling this method

```
viewpager. setOffscreenPageLimit(int)
```

If you pass in an integer that is smaller than 1, it has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is the normal behaviour of the ViewPager, because it will always try to stay ahead of the user by rendering tabs that limit with the drawing area. I personally don't recommend creating a custom ViewPager as you are almost sure to break functionality unless you really know what you are doing. Your adapter class should look something like this:

```
public class YourCustomPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private List<Fragment> fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String> titleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public WizardPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        fragmentList.add(fragment);
        titleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        super.getPageTitle(position);
        return titleList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragmentList.size();
    }
}
```

and you should add your fragments as such:

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     ...
     YourCustomPagerAdapter adapter = new YourCustomPagerAdapter (getSupportFragmentManager());
     adapter.addFragment(FragmentOne.newInstance(), "Frag 1");
     adapter.addFragment(FragmentTwo.newInstance(), "Frag 2");
     viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
     ...
 }
```

Comment: I don't have created a custom viewpager, it's the default android viewpager. And as I mentioned in my comment a few posts below, I also got another android project with a viewpager, in which this behaviour doesn't occur. So I thought it has to be a mistake in my current project. And by the way...I changed my adapter to your solution, but unfortunately still no success

Comment: No success of doing what? Your question was regarding a ViewPager's expected behaviour. If you specify further I might be able to help.

Comment: I really want that bounty :P

Answer (score -1):

i think the error is the adapter:

```
   /**
     * Setzt die neuen News.
     **/
    public void updateNewsList(ArrayList<News> list) {
        //mNewsList = list;
        mNewsList.clear();
        mNewsList.addAll(list);
        /**
         * Notifies the attached observers that the underlying data has been changed
         * and any View reflecting the data set should refresh itself.
         */
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

error reason :this list is diffent entity for that adapter.